# Wireframe / Lines Stitching

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to resolve some stitching while using a mesh in wireframe mode and some lines represented at the same coordinates as the mesh. The idea is that they are used for two representation modes of the same data in my software.

I created a jsFiddle for testing purpose : http://jsfiddle.net/Ludobaka/c0tq3gd0/

I already tried some tips from ThreeJS topics here as :

- Using ***renderOrder*** of THREE.*Mesh* to render my wireframe first and using ***depthFunc*** of THREE.*Material* with THREE.*LessDepth* for the line representation.
- Using ***polygonOffset*** property of THREE.*Material* of the mesh like the following code :

  ```
  mat.polygonOffset = true;
  mat.polygonOffsetFactor = 1.0;
  mat.polygonOffsetUnit = 4.0;
  ```

  But it looks like because wireframe is using glContext.LINES, it is not affected by these properties.

I want my wireframe always be on top of the lines. Do you know an other way to proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: Is http://jsfiddle.net/c0tq3gd0/3/ satisfactory?

Comment: I've already thought about this one, but I may have some objects between the camera and the wireframe, and I want the wireframe to be hidden in this case. But thank you for helping !

I've read that threejs r83 will get onBeforeRender and onAfterRender for Object3D. I was thinking of implementing a depth value offset in projection matrix just for the Lines, as explained in Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics 9.1.

I'm upgrading my ThreeJS rev and I will try to give a solution here, if somebody else have to resolve the same problem ;)

Comment: It is important that you provide _all_ your requirements in your question and in your fiddle.